# cx_Freeze import error

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

So after typing "python setup.py build" and running the exe, it returns

```
ImportError: No module named '_frozen_importlib_external'
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: importlib install failed
```

This is my setup.py, and I'm using python 3.5:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name='myexe',
      version='0.1',
      description='mydescription',
      executables = [Executable('filename.py')])
```

Does anyone have any idea of what's happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has already been reported on : https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/156/running-frozen-app-with-python-35-no

I personally had the same problem as you and after making some changes to finder.py located in my python3.5/site-packages/cx_freeze folder , I managed to bypass the error you currently have.